# How can I use the Visual Studio C/C++ Compiler (cl.exe) to pre-process my objective-C code?

Tags: c++, objective-c, visual-studio-2015, compiler-construction, preprocessor

I have some old Objective-C code which I am trying to compile using my custom-build framework. This build framework preprocesses the source files, then compiles them to C-Source code and then uses Cl.exe to do the rest of compiling.

However, when I try to do the same with VS2015, it fails in my preprocessing phase. As from VS2015 `VCRuntime.h` is included in all files indirectly and uses newer C++ features e.g. Variadic Macros. So my preprocessor fails.

So, is there a way to use the Cl.exe to preprocess my source code e.g. unwinding #includes, evaluating #defines etc without being concerned about the actual code? I tried `cl.exe /Tp` but didn't work. However this option does understand `#imports`

Comment: Has no one tried this ever? It should be possible right? C++ and Obj-C share a lot of similar syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

The `cl.exe /Tp /E /I` command could work to some extend preprocessing both `objective-c (.m)` and `c (.c)` source files. However it fails to parse few of the `COM` related code.

Then I found [an open-source C-Pre-Processor](https://github.com/danmar/simplecpp) that can successfully preprocess `.c, .cpp and .m files`. The benefit of this tool is, it supports C++ 11 features as well e.g. variadic template etc.